# Lookup field not working in lightning mode

Tags: lightning, lookup

I'm trying to create a service sold and select a quote line item, but, using a lookup field cannot select a valid QLI.

The same process works fine in classic mode, and it's the only lookup field that doesn't work properly.

I already tryed to use the same object as lookup field in others objects, but the result is the same. It's only possible to search by ID, since the QLI doesn't have a name, also, if I choose to search all, a correct list appears, but select the item don't update the field and Save fails because I turn that field mandatory.

Steps with images:
1 - Trying to find the QLI
[image: Search]

2 - Search after ckick in magnifying
[image: Magnifiyng]

3 - After select a valus from search
[image: Select]

Comment: Hi Pedro, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Can you please [edit] your post to be more detailed and clear about what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried so far, and were precisely you are stuck?

Comment: Hi, I added more detail and also added some pics to be more clear.